# How to check whether my Domain is Blacklisted on Facebook or not?

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I have a Facebook page of my blog but whenever I try to schedule post my blog article links on the Facebook page The Facebook automatically delete my schedule post and even some time they do not publish it can it be the reason that my domain name has been declared SPAM by the Facebook how to check it.

Comment: If the domain was blocked, you should get a message saying so when you try to post any link to it manually via the FB UI.

Comment: @CBroe No i m Not getting this kind of message actually i have seen my some of the article are being published and some are deleted from the schedule itself

Comment: Well then a blocked domain is likely rather not the cause of this. I’d start analyzing this by checking what API response you get when making those posts.

Comment: @CBroe I think my domain is not blocked because it's not showing that this website URL is blocked by Facebook but I don't know what is the main reason I think I should test it by buying s new Domain name

Comment: @SnehaChoudhary have you got a solution.  I am also facing the same problem some post URL being published and some not. "We can't review this website because the content doesn't meet our Community Standards. If you think this is a mistake, please let us know."

Answer (score 3):

Use the Facebook sharing debugger.

If you input a URL that redirects to the blocked URL, it will initially say "this webpage contains a blocked URL. If you input the blocked URL directly, it will say "We can't review this website because the content doesn't meet our Community Standards. If you think this is a mistake, please let us know." You also get this message if you put in a URL that redirects to the blocked URL a second time.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/

Answer (score 0):

:It is often hard to tell the reason for this but, you can definitely get out of this by following the proper instructions.

First check if your domain is prohibited or just penalized by the search engine. Or, maybe it is neither prohibited nor punishable by the domain name. It could be, you just managed to screw up your site.
Simply check this via online tool -isitban.com by entering your domain or website url.
Once found banned then, check your website content & remove content which is violating any Community Standards of facebook.
Once you are done with content optimisation then send your Facebook website again for review